# How to do a quick "pull-merge" in gitpython?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

EDIT: this was edited because I made a mistake in the example.

---

Assume I have a very simple git structure:

1. A single remote branch, called "brem"
2. A local, called "bloc"

   ---

   self._repo = git.Repo(args.full_path_to_repo)

Having made a change to a `bloc`, I can push it to the remote using

```
self._repo.git.add(update=True)
self._repo.index.commit("commit_message")
origin = self._repo.remote(name=self.origin_name)
origin.push()
```

I would like to now pull and merge this change into the another local repo.

I do

```
def _pull(self):
    origin = self._repo.remote(name=self.origin_name)
    try:
        origin.pull()
    except git.exc.GitCommandError as ex:
        print "There was nothing new to pull"
        return
```

which pulls the remote correctly.

Then I try

```
    origin = self._repo.remote(name=self.origin_name)
    self._repo.git.merge(origin)
```

which gives an exception:

> stderr: 'merge: bitbucket_repo - not something we can merge'

---

**What is the correct way of merging pulled changes from a remote branch `brem` to a local branch `bloc`, assuming no conflicts?**

---

EDIT2:

I managed to get it working with simply

```
self._repo.git.execute('git pull')
```

But this defeats the purpose of using a library.
I would still like to see the correct way of doing this

Comment: You'll need to specify which branch from the remote to merge, not the entire remote repo. Pull works by merging whatever remote branch the current local branch is tracking, but you'll need to specify a branch of you're pulling from some other remote repo.

Comment: Allright, assune the remote branch is `edf`. How do i specify that?

Comment: Not too familiar with gitpython but I think something like origin.heads.edf maybe?

Comment: Docs for accessing various references in gitpython are here: https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#advanced-repo-usage

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to specify a git reference from the remote to merge into the current HEAD. If it's a branch and you know the branch name you would do:

```
self._repo.git.merge(origin.heads["branch_name"])
```

See docs on accessing references in gitpython here: https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#advanced-repo-usage

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Remote' object has no attribute 'heads'`

Comment: `self._repo.git.merge( self._repo.heads[self.master_name])` gives no error, but does not merge anything